# How do I stop Unity from starting windows maximised?

Tags: 10.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop Unity from starting windows maximised?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39014/how-do-i-stop-unity-from-starting-windows-maximised)

How do I stop Unity from starting windows maximised?

I like lots of windows spread across my desktop.

It is fine on a netbook, but not on a large desktop.