# How do I stop Unity from starting windows maximised?

Tags: unity

I do not find an option to change the window behaviour that was in Appearance Properties.

In particular I find it very annoying that Nautilus is always maximised when opening it.

Is there a way to change that default behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using Compiz to do this?

Comment: @Alan: Do you have a suggestion where I should look in ccsm? I do not see it immediately

Comment: I posted an answer. It works in Ubuntu Classic, but I'm not sure if Unity by default will override it. Hope it all works out for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window is maximized if it is started with a size over 75% of the display.
You can unmaximize hitting the button or double clicking the title.
Note that there is a bug in this behavior, not all windows respecting that.

[Why do firefox 4 and evolution always open maximized in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35011/why-do-firefox-4-and-evolution-always-open-maximized-in-unity)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/754214

*I'm at mobile so I wiil fix the layout when I get home.*

Comment: OK, but that's for the Dash. And I have set the form-factor on 'Desktop' so my dash is not maximised anymore, but Nautilus still is every time I open it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't pay attention. I think this can help http://askubuntu.com/questions/35011/why-do-firefox-4-and-evolution-always-open-maximized-in-unity I'm at mobile right now, I will fix the answer when I get home.

Comment: There is a bug for something like that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/754214

Comment: It has to do with the 75%-rule. When I close nautilus windowed, but smaller so under the 75%, then it also opens windowed. Previously I closed Nautilus not small enough so it opened maximised again. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to change that number of 75%?

Comment: I don't know joris. I will search and tell you if I find something ;-)

Answer (score 10):

In 11.04, when Unity is the default for desktops as well as netbooks, this behaviour will be set based on screen size by default, but also customizable in Appearance Properties. You will be able to let the system decide, or configure it always to maximise (except blacklisted apps) or never to maximise.

Comment: I'm running 11.04 and getting annoyed with Firefox always starting maximised. I can't find this setting in Appearance Properties. Did it end up being set somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

- Install **CompizConfig Settings
  Manager.**

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```

  - Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or **Preferences >
  CompizConfig Settings Manager** in
  **Ubuntu Classic**
- Navigate to the **Place Windows** tab[image]
- Adjust **Placement Mode** to your
  liking.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it does not change the 75% rule. So I will just ensure that I set nautilus just under 75% of the screen so it is not maximised when I open it again.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work. I mainly use Ubuntu Classic, so most of what I post for Unity is done with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

#### 10.10

That seems to be the wanted behaviour, according to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/667305):

> That's wanted. Unity in maverick is the netbook edition, made for small screen. So, all applications are maximized by default.

I guess you will have to wait until the Desktop version of Unity is released, which will happen ["as soon as possible"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9941/when-will-compiz-based-version-unity-be-available-for-testing).

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because my OpenID is broken so I can't log in as a privileged user, but (at least on 11.10) you can address the 75% rule in Compiz, too: it is currently under Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Experimental

Set this value to 100% and all windows should open at their previous size.