# How to make all windows appear in center of the screen when you start them up?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I want my program's windows to appear in the center of the screen because when i start a program it all was hides the dock. or if the dock i allways on under them.

And im talking unity here:)

Comment: Possible duplicate - does this AU question and answer help?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/39014/how-do-i-stop-unity-from-starting-windows-maximised

Answer (score 2):

In CompizConfig Settings Manager go to:

Window Management -->Place windows.
Change Placement Mode from Smart to centered.

For me this fixes the problem in 11.04.

Comment: I am using 12.04, and windows were appearing partially under the top panel.  I changed this same setting to 'Cascade' a few days ago and it seems to have fixed it.  I don't think the 'Smart' setting is very smart :).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can forget about that, right now it's not possible to center windows and apps on the screen. That's why I haven't upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 yet.

In Ubuntu 10.04.2 you could do it buy either editing the gconf-editor.

```
/apps/metacity/general/focus_new_windows
```

smart to centered, and

```
/apps/compiz/plugins/place/screen0/options/mode
```

Options are:

Algorithm to use for window placement (0 = Cascade, 1 = Centered, 2 = Smart, 3 = Maximize, 4 = Random)

setting: 1

Or simply by using the compizconfig-settings-manager.

Now both methods do not work under Ubuntu 11.04 anymore!

It freaking sucks to be honest with you, I don't know why linux users are so obsessed with windows popping up on the right or left...

Kind regards,
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

To force new windows to be centred set

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/put/screen0/options/window_center
```

to true in the gconf configuration editor.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 15.10. What version are you testing it on?